# How do I get my duplicants to use the recreation room?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen Not Included, I have a recreation room but the duplicants are not using it, even though they have scheduled downtime. How can I get them to use the rec room and get the bonus?

Answer (score 3):

By making sure they have enough free time to do, besides their basic necessities, also entertainment activities such as hanging out at the water cooler or dancing. Most of the time a two time slot of break will not suffice to cover basic necessities AND the time they spend from commuting from their workplace to the main base when the base gets bigger.